# Load HTML if User belongs to a certain group

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I want show a link only if the user belongs to a group.

html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="boss").user_set.all() %}
    {% if user in users_in_group %}
    <li><a href='/register'>Create User</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I did the following

view:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    a = request.user.groups.count()
    if a > 0:
        #a = request.user.groups.all()[0] #Trae el nombre del grupo 
        a = "jefe"
    else:
        a = "no user groups"    
else:
    a = "user is not log"
```

base.html:

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if a in "jefes" %}
      <li><a href='/usuarios'>Usuarios</a></li>
    {% endif %}   
  {% endif %}
```

I do not know if it's the best but I served.